# Enterprise Integration between systems

Tags: architecture, integration, enterprise, bus

I have an architectural problem which is driving me crazy.

The requirement is to process of a list of messages on a bus  that must be executed sequentially, because of requirements process. So I have to execute the Message number 1 always before than Message 2. 
All messages of  the same customer are logically grouped  by a unique customer code.
If a message crashes I have to block the entire message list belonging to that customer, and I have to excecute them again afterwards (without losing them otherwise there is a mismatch with the calling system )
All my doubts are about the scalability; let me explain :
Which solution could allow me one day to "scale up" if I am forced to process messages sequentially ?
I can't increase the number of Worker which process the messages on the bus because, in that case, it could happend that the Message 2 will be processed as first (and it will send me an error because the message n. 1 is not finished yet )
Could you suggest me solutions / patterns / best practices that can be used on the bus ?
Do you think that a tool such as BitzTalk can help in this situation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Event Sourcing](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html) [CQRS](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html)